# Remember checked options for user on form. Material UI/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, browser, material-ui

Looking for the best way to cache a users checkbox selections with material UI the browser/react. I would prefer to just use the browser and temporary storage as the options only need to persist if the user navigates away and comes back to the form in the same session. I do not need to save them on the user object as they do not need to persist through multiple sessions. Suggestion for the most optimal way to save a simple checkbox form selections? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I found the best modern solution to use react hooks with local storage. To pull an item on load of the state component. Use the following guidelines

//Get Stored:

```js
const [state, setName] = useState(() => {
  // getting stored value
  const saved = localStorage.getItem("name");
  const initialValue = JSON.parse(saved);
  return initialValue || "";
});
```

To set an item:
We can also use the useEffect React Hook to perform side effects, such as storing data in the browser storage. This makes this Hook a perfect place to call the setItem method.

Open the components/Form1.js file and add the following code above the return statement:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // storing input name
  localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(name));
}, [name]
```

Blog Post I followed: https://blog.logrocket.com/using-localstorage-react-hooks/